# Find variable values in a JavaScript logical expression that will make expression evaluate to true

Tags: javascript

I have a data structure that is published as a stream of event data:

```
first = 12,
second = 20,
third = 120,
fourth = false,
fifth = "Fault"
```

Below I have Alarms/Conditions about the values above, that will produce alarms on the back-end if an Alarm logical expression evaluates to true.
Eg. 
Alarm1:
`(first < 10 && second > 25) || (first > 7 && second <= 22)`

Alarm2:
`fourth = true && (fifth == "Fault" || fifth == "Error")`

If my expressions are expressed in JavaScipt syntax how can I programmatically find what variable(s) values/combinations will make a logical expression true.

For example:
Alarm1: first = 9, second = 20  will evaluate to true. (I want to find these values)
        first = 9  will not be enough to evaluate to true.

So how to find one or more variable values that will make conditions evaluate to true.

Any JavaScript parsers that can help me figure this out?

Thanks,
Rad

Comment: Figuring out possible values for the (in)equivalences is easy, after that it becomes a [SAT problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a simple state machine would work.

The state machine knows what variable names to watch for, the boolean expression to evaluate, and a callback to execute.  The callback receives the result of the boolean expression.

When a variable assignment expression is added to the state machine, the machine checks if all of the variables it's watching have been accumulated.  If not, the machine just stores the variable assignment and waits for the next one.  Otherwise the machine uses its accumulated variable assignments to evaluate the boolean expression.

This ES6 code implements such a state machine.  It calls `eval()`, which opens a huge security hole.  So please be careful with the JavaScript being fed into this code.

```js
function State(
  _variableNames /* array */,
  _booleanExpression /* string */,
  _callback /* function(boolean) -> void */)
{
  /* Mapping of variable names to their local assignments.
     E.g. 'first' -> 'let first = 42'

     See this.addVar(). */
  let _variableMap = new Map();
  
  function haveAllValuesBeenSet()
  {
    return _variableNames.every(name => _variableMap.has(name));
  }
  
  function getSafeAssignment(assignment)
  {
    /* Turn global assignments into local assignments
       by prepending 'let'.  This way the assigments
       won't pollute the global namespace when they're
       run thru eval(). */
       
    if (assignment.startsWith('let '))
      return assignment;
    else if (assignment.startsWith('var '))
      return 'let ' + assignment.substring(4);
    else
      return 'let ' + assignment;    
  }
  
  function evalExpression()
  {
    let assigments = '';
    
    /* IE 11 doesn't support the Map.values property. */
    for (let [_, assignment] of _variableMap)
    {
      assigments += assignment + ';\n';
    }
    
    let expression = assigments + _booleanExpression;
    
    /* Uncomment to see the full expression
       that's being evaluated. */
    console.log(expression);
    
    try
    {
      return eval(expression);
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
      console.log('ERROR in evalExpression(): ' + ex.message + '\n' + expression);
    }
  }

  /* Add a variable assigment to the state machine,
     e.g. "second = 55" */  
  this.addVar =
    function(assignment /* string */)
    {
      let parts = assignment.split('=').map(s => s.trim());
      let name = parts[0];
      let safeAssigment = getSafeAssignment(assignment);
      
      if (!_variableNames.includes(name))
        return;
      
      if (!_variableMap.get(name))
        _variableMap.set(name, safeAssigment);

      if (haveAllValuesBeenSet())
      {
        _callback(evalExpression());        
        _variableMap.clear();
      }
    };
}

function StateAggregator()
{
  let _states = [];
  
  this.add =
    function(state)
    {
      _states.push(state);
    };
    
  this.applyAssignment =
    function(assignment)
    {
      for (let state of _states)
      {
        state.addVar(assignment);
      }
    };
}

/* Create two state machines. */

var firstAndSecondState = new State(
  ['first', 'second'],
  '(first < 10 && second > 25) || (first > 7 && second <= 22)',
  function(booleanResult)
  {
    console.log('firstAndSecondState: ' + booleanResult);
  });

var fourthAndFifthState = new State(
  ['fourth', 'fifth'],
  'fourth === true && (fifth === "Fault" || fifth === "Error")',
  function(booleanResult)
  {
    console.log('fourthAndFifthState: ' + booleanResult);
  });
  
/* For convenience, a simple aggregator that allows a single variable
   assigment to be broadcast to all of the state machines. */
   
var agg = new StateAggregator();
agg.add(firstAndSecondState);
agg.add(fourthAndFifthState);
  
var dataStream = [
  'first = 12',
  'second = 20',
  'third = 120',
  'fourth = false',
  'fifth = "Fault"'
  ];
  
for (let assignment of dataStream)
{
  agg.applyAssignment(assignment);
}
```

Comment: OP does not want to know when during the event stream the alarm will sound, he wants to figure out (generate) a complete state that will cause the alarm to sound from nothing but the description of the formula.